# Spaces appear in PHP output from Powershell after 79 characters

Tags: php, powershell, echo

Unusual problem here! I'm executing Powershell from within PHP. Here is an example where we capture the output of the Powershell command into $query:

```
$query = shell_exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath -logFile'$logFile' -param1 '$blah'< NUL");
```

Now, this works well for the most part. The Powershell scripts do their thing, and within them use Write-Output to return some data back to the screen/user, as HTML. Example:

```
Write-Output "$logFile<br /><br />"
Write-Output "Blah blah some information<br />"
```

The problem comes when PHP echos $query. On every Write-Output "line" PHP seems to insert a space, or some kind of line break after the 79th character (or whitespace). Sometimes, this coincides with a space and so it's not noticable, but other times it's in the middle of the word. For example when $logFile's value is:

```
L:\transcripts\activedirectory\change-display-name\2012-03-03-235201-abcde-admin.txt<br />
```

It actually ends up looking like this on the screen (notice the space at the end):

```
L:\transcripts\activedirectory\change-display-name\2012-03-03-235201-abcde-admi n.txt
```

Looking at the generated source code shows:

```
L:\transcripts\activedirectory\change-display-name\2012-03-03-235201-itwrm-admi
n.txt<br />
```

Another example would be in Powershell:

```
Write-Output "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<br />"
```

Gives:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<br />
```

It's as though PHP is wrapping the text somehow? Or the output from Write-Output is wrapping it "before" it is sent back to PHP (into $query).

If I echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" in PHP and view the source code, it appears on one single line without the breaks above.

I came across the wordwrap function but couldn't see how this would help. Not quite sure what is going on at the moment...

EDIT: Could this be something to do with the default buffersize of a Powershell console being 80 characters wide?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I bet on Powershell console wordwrapping its output.

Comment: The default window size of cmd.exe is 80 characters.

Comment: Yes it was that. Typing out all the question made me realise. I managed to solve it by increasing the buffer width of the Window at the top of the Powershell script. I don't have enough rep to self after at the moment so can't post the code.

Comment: Did you also try PHP [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) ?

Comment: @AndyArismendi Interesting. Hadn't realised the difference between the two until now. Although I have a solution it's worth knowing!

Comment: Also when PowerShell is run without the start menu shortcut it will assume the default console width (80).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have your answer, but here is the piece of code I add to my script when I have the same problem (something I found on StackOverflow if memory serves me):

```
if ($Host -and $Host.UI -and $Host.UI.RawUI) 
{
    $rawUI = $Host.UI.RawUI
    $oldSize = $rawUI.BufferSize
    $typeName = $oldSize.GetType().FullName
    $newSize = New-Object $typeName (500, $oldSize.Height)
    $rawUI.BufferSize = $newSize
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I found (from heyscriptingguy) :)